# cant connect to dockerized postgresql server

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, api, docker

i have problem with connect to my postgresql database with node.js
running dockerized postgresql server like that (https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/). can connect with pgadmin, but cant connect with node. didnt see any process on this port. what error i see:

```
MacBook-Pro-Maxim:nodejs lucio$ docker logs 5cc44d01bf4ada729e5f1c71157e4eba5cb6fa9fd40122f384b423fbd1ae13a7
2019-12-28T12:38:53: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
2019-12-28T12:38:53: PM2 log: App [index:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-12-28T12:38:53: PM2 log: App [index:0] online
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:32775
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',

  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 32775 }
```

database.js 
here is simple example of my DataBase class. just constuctor of params for connecting and simpe query request method.

```
const {
  Pool,
  Client
} = require('pg')
const sqlQueryGenerator = require('sql-query-generator')
const sqlGenerator = require('sql')
sqlGenerator.setDialect('postgres')
sqlQueryGenerator.use('postgres')

class DataBase {
  constructor(params) {
    this.base = new Pool(params)
  }
  query(text) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.base.query(text, (err, res) => {
        if (err) reject(err)
        resolve(res)
      })
    })
  }
}

module.exports = DataBase
```

using this module in my api.js file

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' })
const DataBase = require('./database')
const db = new DataBase({
   user     : process.env.USER,
   host     : process.env.HOST,
   database : process.env.TABLE,
   password : process.env.PASSWORD,
   port     : process.env.PORT,
})
```

here is my .env file

```
HOST = localhost
USER = docker
TABLE = docker
PASSWORD = docker
PORT = 32775
```

before run container with node.js api i checking actual port of my postgresql docker container.
how to solve my problem? thx for feedback

Comment: I guess node runs in a different container, so you  need to use the IP of the PostgreSQL container instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @t-niese change my HOST on 127.0.0.1, still cant connect. same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not connect to DB container using `localhost`, here `localhost` mean the Nodejs container not the DB container.

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:32775
```

The connection looking for DB in the nodejs container.

To connect with DB container you have two option.

- Use common network for DB and nodejs and use the service name to connect with Database.

```
HOST = db_container_name
USER = docker
TABLE = docker
PASSWORD = docker
PORT = 5432
```

- Use the Host IP for DB connection.

```
HOST = HOST_IP
USER = docker
TABLE = docker
PASSWORD = docker
PORT = 32775
```

Or better to use docker-compose that handle networking for you and you can refer any container to connect using the name of the container.

Comment: on HOST i should use pg_test or 0.0.0.0, right?
here is example of docker ps command in bash
https://pastebin.com/nzPGxuH2

Comment: No its interface that attached with the container. you can link nodejs container or you can use docker-compose. or the temp fix is to copy the DB Container IP and use that IP. `docker inspect 3663ffa6607f` and grab the IP, but it will change frequently

Comment: did you tried with DB container IP? `docker inspect db_container`?

Comment: what key in this JSON is container IP? "IPAddress"?

Comment: `172.17.0.2` use this IP, but keep in mind this will change frequently or if restarted, so better to use docker networking.https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Using container IP you should use expose port 5432, not publish port

Comment: that's worked! just change to port 5432 and now i can connect to my database

Comment: Perfect. but as I suggest use docker network or docker-compose for permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use your host IP in .env file:

```
HOST = x.x.x.x
```

Comment: change my HOST to 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0, also trying to change on my docker container name. not working. same problem
```Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.01:32775```
```Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:32775```

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a IP address, If you set 0.0.0.0 for any of the listener, that mean you can connect to that listener by using any of the available network interfaces of the docker. If you need to check the connectivity to any of the IP and port you can use telnet client (telnet IP port). First get the container ID:
    ***docker ps***
(First column is for container ID)
Use the container ID to run:
    ***docker inspect <container ID>***
At the bottom,under "NetworkSettings", you can find "IPAddress" Or Just do:
    ***docker inspect <container id> | grep "IPAddress"***

Answer (score 0):

your node js application is running with docker right ? 
If this is the case you have to put the two containers on the same network ( the simplest solution ) , you can do that with docker compose that automatically put all containers to the same network and then you can contact another container by its name.
Or you can inspect the DB container with :

```
 docker container inspect DB_CONTAINER
```

Find the NetworksSettings -> Networks --> Here you will find the network name

Then you can connect your node js container to the same network

```
  docker network connect NETWORK_NAME NODE_CONTAINER_NAME
```

Now you should be able to connect node container to the DB by the DB container host name ( by default is the id of the container , but you can specify an hostname with --hostname argument during docker run command execution )

Hope this help you!!!

Comment: yes, i have two containers. first with nodejs, second with docker. i will try this solution right now.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1CqgWB9T
error with connect
```Error response from daemon: endpoint with name fervent_merkle already exists in network bridge```

Comment: @designervoid maybe your second container is already on the same network , please  use docker inspect to check this and also check in the DB container the hostname , you have to use it to connect your node js process to the database.
Please let me know , hope to help you

Comment: UPD:
Also another solution is connect to docker network by Docker `--network` flag.